# Routing SER cable through a subpannel/junction box without making splices?

Tags: code-compliance, subpanel, service

Due to other constrains I may need to route a SER cable feeding a remote subpanel via a junction box (or another small subpanel for convinience). This junction box will be connected back to back to a main service panel (the main is outside on siding while the said box is inside on the same wall and location connected via short fixture back-to-back).

Questinon: Can the SER cable enter the junction box and than be stripped from outsize sheeth and than individual wires routed to the main service pannel (bypassing any connections in the junction box).

I suppose, if not the alternative could be to use the small subpanel and connect the said SER to a breaker in the inside subpannel hence daisy-chaining the main(braker)->junction subpannel(breaker)->remote subpannel.
Another perhaps could be to splice the SER cable with individual wires designated for individual use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splice to repair damaged 100A aluminum feeder](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/169588/splice-to-repair-damaged-100a-aluminum-feeder)

Comment: Do the individual wires inside the SE-R cable have markings of their own, i.e. a line of text running down the wire?

Comment: So you want to enter a box, remove the outer jacket and exit the box? Yes this can be done inside the box only. The jacket must intact outside the box. We do this when we expect to tap a set of cables inside the box. If going through a nipple to another box no it can not be done that way.

Comment: No marking (text) on individual wires other than color stripe. So technically these cannot leave the box. And due to space limitation I cannot make the "bend" of shethed SER in there.
So I either have to splice them with marked wire (need 3x ISR-1/0 ==> $100 + wire) or just put a 100A breaker in this new subpanel  and feed it from the main.  The later seems cheaper and easier. Thank you for comments!

Comment: I wonder if removing the sheth only for the "bend" area (to use individual wires diameter for min bend) and leaving it on when cable was crossing the nipple to the main panel would be in code?